Is mastrubation permissible in some conditions?
I feel embarrassed asking this. But is it permissible for me to mastrubate just for the reason of semen release and colour check. Both of these reasons are health reasons but I want to clarify that no doctors are involved and I only do it once a month for the reason not to make it a habit and start to do it for desire
By health reasons I mean the reason not for semen to build up and cause long term problems
Please know my intentions are good and even doing it only once a month

What medical reason is this? Seems to me like its just you making up an excuse to deceive yourself.

Performing an inexpert self-diagnosis of reproductive health is not recommended, as it may lead to inaccurate conclusions and delay proper medical evaluation. It is always best to consult a healthcare professional for accurate diagnosis and guidance. Furthermore, If you're in good health and have no concerns, there's no need for constant monitoring.
